# After turning into OSX app, Python subprocess can't call external console command

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I am developing a GUI application using Kivy that in turn it will call an external console program from Python script using `subprocess.Popen` and capture its `stderr` output live. Finally, it works (thanks to SO for this!). I package the application using Pyinstaller, in which it produce an *.app that contains the executable resided in `Contents\MacOS`. If I run this executable directly from within Terminal, it runs well. The stderr output can be capture live. But, if I try to run the *.app directly either using `open` command from Terminal or double click its *.app icon from Finder, the call to `subprocess.Popen` simply halt.

I am not sure about this, but is there any restriction on an OSX app about how it can execute external program?

Comment: Since you aren't running from a terminal when run the `*.app` file, the Python process may not be getting an open file handle for either `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`.

Comment: What command will `subprocess.Popen` run? Are you specifying its full path? Try the full path, because apps executed via the GUI have a different `PATH` than the command line (which I find hugely annoying, but so it is.) If that's not the problem, what error does `Popen` report?

Comment: Turn out, after tracking the code thoroughly, it's not the subprocess call that halt the application. I explain it in answer section of this Q&A page. Thanks for the helps guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the application halt turns out to be not the `subprocess.Popen` call, but the call of `mktemp` that creates a temporary file inside of `*.app folder`, where a Mac app is definitely not permitted to write by default. After commenting this out, the code runs just fine. I'll make note of this and remind myself not to create temp file inside `*.app` folder again!

Comment: you could accept your own answer to show that the issue is resolved.

Comment: Sure, but SO only allow me after two days :)